# white space when looking at responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm not sure if it's a bug, but I see whitespace (sometimes) when looking at the responsive side of things in the chrome browser. I said sometimes because my website manages to fix itself when I refresh. This problem only happens when working with responsive side.[The image is how it looks like to me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnC2c.png)

```js
const fade = document.querySelectorAll('.fade');

window.addEventListener('scroll', checkBoxes);

checkBoxes();

function checkBoxes() {
    const triggerBottom = window.innerHeight / 3.5 * 4;

    fade.forEach(fade => {
        const fadeTop = fade.getBoundingClientRect().top;

        if(fadeTop < triggerBottom) {
            fade.classList.add('show');
        } else {
            fade.classList.remove('show');
        }
    })
}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

:root {
    --shade-background: #FAFAFA;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: "SF Pro Text","SF Pro Icons","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
}

.intro-container {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

.intro-container::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    background-image: url(../images/airpods.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position:center;
    opacity: .9.5;
}

.intro-container .content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
    z-index: 1;
}

.content h1 {
    font-size: 5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.content p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-size: .9rem;
    margin-right: 5px;
}


/* MAIN CONTENT*/

.chapternav {
    background: rgba(245,245,247,0.7);
    padding: 0;
    padding-top: 8px;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 100px;
    z-index: 9987;
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.chapternav-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.chapternav-items {
    margin: 0 34px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    list-style: none;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.chapternav-item {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 -.11765em;
    padding: 0 20px;
}

.chapternav-label {
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 1.33337;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: -.01em;
    font-family: "SF Pro Text","SF Pro Icons","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 17px;
}



/* nav items */

.container {
    margin: 0 auto; /* this will center the page */
    max-width: 960px; /*  use your width here */
}

.container h2 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
}

.fade {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    background-color: var(--shade-background);
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    height: 450px;
    transform: translateX(400%);
    transition: transform 2s ease;
    /* animation: fadeIn  4s; */
}

.fade h3 {
    margin-bottom: 1rem;
    font-size: 40px;
    line-height: 1.1;
    font-family: "SF Pro Display","SF Pro Icons","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    letter-spacing: 0em;
}

.fade p {
    max-width: 300px;
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 1.23536;
    font-weight: 400;
    letter-spacing: -.022em;
    font-family: "SF Pro Text","SF Pro Icons","Helvetica Neue","Helvetica","Arial",sans-serif;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin: 15px 0;
}

.fade img {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}

.learn-copy {
    color: #0071e3;
    margin-top: 3rem;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.icon-arrow {
    color: #0071e3;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.learn-copy:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}


/* javascript */

.fade:nth-of-type(even) {
    transform: translateX(-400%);
}

.fade.show {
    transform: translateX(0);
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
    0% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
    }

/* end of javascript */
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.2/css/all.min.css" integrity="sha512-HK5fgLBL+xu6dm/Ii3z4xhlSUyZgTT9tuc/hSrtw6uzJOvgRr2a9jyxxT1ely+B+xFAmJKVSTbpM/CuL7qxO8w==" crossorigin="anonymous" />
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Maven+Pro:wght@400;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="intro-container">
        <div class="content">
            <h1>AirPods</h1>
            <p>Don't Just Listen, Feel It</p>
            <!-- <button>Explore</button> -->
            <!-- <i class="fa fa-arrow-down"></i> -->
        </div>
    </div>

    <nav class='chapternav'>
        <div class="chapternav-wrapper">
            <ul class="chapternav-items">
                <li class="chapternav-item">
                    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0Ij48cGF0aCBkPSJNMSAxM2gtMXYtMWgxdjF6bTIyLTFoLTF2MWgxdi0xem0tMjAtMWgtMXYzaDF2LTN6bTE4IDBoLTF2M2gxdi0zem0tMTQgMGgtMXYzaDF2LTN6bTEwLTFoLTF2NWgxdi01em0tMTIgMGgtMXY1aDF2LTV6bTE0LTFoLTF2N2gxdi03em0tMTAgMGgtMXY3aDF2LTd6bTItMmgtMXYxMGgxdi0xMHptNCAwaC0xdjEwaDF2LTEwem0tMi0yaC0xdjE0aDF2LTE0eiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==">
                    <span class='chapternav-label'>AirPods</span>
                <li class="chapternav-item">
                    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0Ij48cGF0aCBkPSJNMSAxM2gtMXYtMWgxdjF6bTIyLTFoLTF2MWgxdi0xem0tMjAtMWgtMXYzaDF2LTN6bTE4IDBoLTF2M2gxdi0zem0tMTQgMGgtMXYzaDF2LTN6bTEwLTFoLTF2NWgxdi01em0tMTIgMGgtMXY1aDF2LTV6bTE0LTFoLTF2N2gxdi03em0tMTAgMGgtMXY3aDF2LTd6bTItMmgtMXYxMGgxdi0xMHptNCAwaC0xdjEwaDF2LTEwem0tMi0yaC0xdjE0aDF2LTE0eiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==">
                    <span class='chapternav-label'>AirPods</span>                    
                </li>
                <li class="chapternav-item">
                    <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciIHdpZHRoPSIyNCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIyNCIgdmlld0JveD0iMCAwIDI0IDI0Ij48cGF0aCBkPSJNMSAxM2gtMXYtMWgxdjF6bTIyLTFoLTF2MWgxdi0xem0tMjAtMWgtMXYzaDF2LTN6bTE4IDBoLTF2M2gxdi0zem0tMTQgMGgtMXYzaDF2LTN6bTEwLTFoLTF2NWgxdi01em0tMTIgMGgtMXY1aDF2LTV6bTE0LTFoLTF2N2gxdi03em0tMTAgMGgtMXY3aDF2LTd6bTItMmgtMXYxMGgxdi0xMHptNCAwaC0xdjEwaDF2LTEwem0tMi0yaC0xdjE0aDF2LTE0eiIvPjwvc3ZnPg==">
                    <span class='chapternav-label'>AirPods</span>                    
                </li>                
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <h2>Wireless to the Fullest</h2>
            <div class="fade">
                    <img src="../images/earphonesbackdrop.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="text">
                    <h3>Get 3% <br>Daily Cash back <br>
                        with Apple Card.</h3>
                    <p>Consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                        Asperiores pariatur modi quis omnis non obcaecati inventore 
                        ad amet voluptates commodi. etxcepturi, illum.</p>
                    <span class="learn-copy">Learn more</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fade">
                <div class="text">
                    <h3>Say it in a way <br>only you can.</h3>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                        Asperiores pariatur commodi. etxcepturi, illum modi amet.</p>
                    <span class="learn-copy">Learn more</span>
                </div>
                    <img src="../images/airpods2.jpg " alt="">
                </div>
            <div class="fade">
                <img src="../images/airpods3.jpg " alt="">
                <div class="text">
                    <h3>Magic runs <br>in the family.</h3>
                    <p>Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. 
                        Asperiores pariatur commodi. etxcepturi, illumdolar illum.</p>
                    <span class="learn-copy">Learn more</span>
                </div>
            </div>                      
    </div>
<script src='script.js'></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Welcome. Tell us more about your problem, pls. Nothing is clear from your description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's all thank to your `transform: translateX(400%);` that set's element far into right side.
Default browser behaviour will be to stretch body to fit all elements in it. That's why it looks like on your screenshot.

Try adding `overflow-x: hidden` to your `.container` class and see if that helps you.